# I'm trying to make this code click the button

Tags: javascript, button, click, getelementsbyclassname

Hey I'm not an experienced coder, just looked at some videos online and now I'm trynna do this.

The code has to fill in text before it is able to click the button otherwise it won't go to the next page.

I managed to get it to fill the text, but I observed that it takes a bit of time for it to fill, around 200 miliseconds.

The class name is `button-submit`.

The code I wrote is

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('button-submit')[0].click()
```

And the error I get is:

> Error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

When I put the code in manually it clicks the button, however when I make it activate itself it says the error above.

I think I might have to add a delay but I'm not to sure.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post your complete code

Comment: I don't have a code. I'm using an extension that activates the function when it's on a specific url. The function is 'document.getElementsByClassName('button-submit')[0].click()'

Comment: Looks like 'button-submit' doesn't exist at the moment when you are clicking. Did you check a readiness of the page before the code invocation?

Comment: I think you're right Marten. What could I do to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one function which will call only when it's needed.

- If you have input field then you can do something like this:

```
// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("input-filed");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Trigger the button element with a click
    handleSubmit();
  }
});

//Submitt function to manage button click.
function handleSubmit(){
 //find button with query selector it will select automatically first element.
 var buttonEle = document.querySelector(".button-submit");
 buttonEle.click();
}
```

I hope this will help you.